# How to check two attributes with Simple HTML DOM?

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I need to get a very specific tag using Simple HTML DOM, and have to check two attributes to do this, but I'm not sure how. Right now I have this:

```
foreach($html->find("ul[class=someclass]") as $step1)
```

But within that same `<ul>` tag there is also an `id` attribute that equals, let's say, "xyz". So how can I check both? I'm assuming something like this (although it doesn't seem to work):

```
foreach($rt_html->find("ul[class=results_ul, id=xyz]") as $step1)
```

Any help?

Comment: Do the `<ul>` elements themselves have the `id` property or is it an element inside? Perhaps a sample HTML would help.

Comment: This is the code I am trying to pull from: `<ul id="movie_results_ul" class="results_ul">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of these should work:

- ul#xyz[class=results_ul]
- ul.results_ul[id=xyz]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that library, but if Musa's answer does not help, try this:

```
$myElements = array();
foreach($html->find("ul[class=someclass]") as $step1) {
    echo "found some class\n";
    if (isset($step1->id) {
       echo "found {$step->id}\n";
    }
    if (isset($step1->id) && $step1->id == 'xyz') {
        $myElements[] = $step1;
    }
}
var_dump($myElements);
```

Comment: While in theory that would work, simple_html_dom doesn't seem to like that.

Comment: So, what happens? It could be a problem, that the attribute id ist not available on each node. In this case do this: if (isset($step1->id) && $step1->id == 'xyz') {

Comment: I just get nothing when I go to print it.

Comment: I added some debug output to the code. This should help you getting for insight on what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I think I have another problem, though. There are a few classes on the page with the same name, but for some reason it is only getting the first. Any way I can specify which one to pull from?

Comment: Multiple elements with the same class are exactly what classes are made for. You specified ul with that class in your find, though. You should get all then. If you only want specific ones, you need to adjust your find. Maybe the ul are all in a div with the specific id? Then something like this should work: find('#theid ul.someclass') - I just now realized, that you try to access the class as attribute. But that should be done with the "." notation. But maybe it was only your example...